# Is it possible to revert Visual Studio subversions?

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Due to a variety of problems that can pop up in a build process when upgrading Visual Studio, I'd like to be able to revert, for instance, from Visual Studio 15.3.3 to Visual Studio 15.3.2. In previous versions of Visual Studio, it was as simple as going to Programs and Features, finding the update that updated Visual Studio and reverting it, but because updates are now done through the Visual Studio Installer, this no longer seems to be possible.

This is mostly a question for future disaster-proofing: we've seen some breaking changes between versions of Visual Studio lately, and we'd like to know how to revert if something goes really, terribly wrong.

Preliminary searches for reverting just the compiler also haven't returned anything -- for C#, it's possible to get specific .Net compilers through NuGet, and we were hoping it would be the same for native C++.